# Flashing Screen or Blinking Screen in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

please may you tell me how i can turn off back light of android device, i try through the setBrightness method but it not works on emulator

my main task is to develop an android application in which whenever any event is occurs then a system have to alert the user by such an alarm in which some mp3 file is playing and flashing screen or blinking screen is showing.

I do the Mp3 file playing task, but how I can do for the Blinking Screen.

I use the Services, not in activity, so cant use the WindowManager, so please there is any way to do this by helping methods which call through Service instead of Activity.

Comment: hey anybody read the question, if any one have the ideas then tell me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emulator does not support brightness changing. For example, if you go to phone settings and change brightness there, nothing will happen. You need a real device if you want to see brightness changes.

Comment: yes, its right, but is there any mechanism to see the changes on amulator

Comment: I guess you can get the current level and print it out